# How to make a checkbox option disabled once only a single checkbox is checked?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Problem:

I have 2 checkbox - consider option A and option B

At least one of them should be checked, so if any of the one is unchecked the other should be disabled. If both of them is checked, both should not be disabled. In short they must not be a case where both can be unchecked.

I'm using vue-bootstrap checkbox component, which has a disabled property, but I cannot make it dynamic according to my condition. Here is the code:

```
<b-form-checkbox-group v-model="selectedFruit" @change="changeFruits">
  <b-form-checkbox v-for="fruit in availableFruits" :key="fruit.id" :value="fruit.name" :disabled="checkifDisabled">
    {{ fruit.name }}
  </b-form-checkbox>
</b-form-checkbox-group>
```

I'm trying to use the vue computed property to do this, but not getting exactly what to target inside the computed property.

```
selectedFruit: [],

availableFruits: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Apple',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Mango',
    }
],

computed: {
  checkifDisabled: function() {
      /// Need to do something here to achieve this
      return true
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a method to `disabled`, which checks whether the checkbox should be disabled or not.
In your case you want to check if there's only one item in the selected array, and disable the checkbox which value is in the array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedFruit: [],
      availableFruits: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Banana'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Strawberry'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Cherry'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'Apple'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isDisabled(fruit) {
      const {
        selectedFruit
      } = this
      return selectedFruit.length === 1 && selectedFruit[0] === fruit.name
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-2">
  <b-form-checkbox-group v-model="selectedFruit">
    <b-form-checkbox v-for="fruit in availableFruits" :key="fruit.id" :value="fruit.name" :disabled="isDisabled(fruit)">
      {{ fruit.name }}
    </b-form-checkbox>
  </b-form-checkbox-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a additional attribute to use in v-model and add the following property in the checkbox tag, Also remove the :value part since its no longer needed

```
<b-form-checkbox-group v-model="selectedFruit" @change="changeFruits">
  <b-form-checkbox v-for="(fruit, index) in availableLaws" :key="fruit.id" v-model="fruit.pick" value="picked"
      unchecked-value="not_picked" :disabled="fruit.pick === 'picked'">
    {{ fruit.name }}
  </b-form-checkbox>
</b-form-checkbox-group>
```

and your data be like

```
data() {
 return {
  selectedLaws: [],

  availableLaws: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Apple',
      pick: 'not_picked' // new change
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Mango',
      pick: 'not_picked' //// new change
    }
 ],
};
}
```

No need to use computed property here

Comment: Its not working. Idk both the checkboxes becomes checked when i put this code.

Comment: In v-for , change availableFruits to availableLaws

Comment: That was a mistake when i copied from code! it doesn't work even with that correction

Comment: I have done changes in the data section and v-for

Comment: Sorry, It still didn't work, I hope the index is not needed in v-for, as its never used. Anyway tried with and without it. Shouldn't the value property be dynamic ? instead of just name ?

Comment: check this out https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox